# iPhone different screen sizes in flash? (Getting Black Bars)

Tags: ios, iphone, actionscript-3, flash

I'm new to the whole world of coding, and actionscript 3 is my first real experience, so sorry if I don't understand your answer straight away.

I've built an iPhone app using Adobe Flash CC in AIR for iOS. All the code is either in the timeline or separate .as files (so not using documents classes).

The core concept of the game is randomly generated objects fall from the top of the screen and the user has to tap them to make them disappear before they touch the bottom.

My problem is my document size is `640 x 960`. I think this fits the iPhone 4 (haven't tested that) but when I test it on my iPhone 5s I get back bars at the top and bottom. Obviously they have different screen sizes but I want the app to be able to run on many all the different size iPhones.

I have spent hours googling this and still don't understand what I'm meant to do. I've tried playing around with the `stage.scaleMode` settings but nothing changes. I have also added a file called `default-568h@2x.png` (just a green rectangle with the dimensions `640 x 1136`) in the included files but this doesn't show either.

So essentially I want to know how to change my app and AS3 code to allow my app to fit all the different size iPhones?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: The last time I fooled around with iOS publishing in Flash (CS 4?), it acted like the document bounds were more suggestions than absolute: the space outside the document area (typically represented in flash as a grayish zone) would be partially visible in the document background color.  Any movieclips in that area would also be visible, same as if you opened a swf in the browser without embedding it in an HTML page.

Comment: I'd heard this too, but I tried extending my background and putting a couple of MovieClips outside the document bounds and it's still black bars on my iphone.

Comment: I'd try making the document match the larger screen and seeing what happens in that case.  If that doesn't work, you've got a real head-scratcher on your hands.

Comment: Maybe I should change the document size to the biggest iPhone (the iPhone 6 plus) and then see what happens. I could change the properties to stagewidth etc rather than x. I'll see what happens

Comment: This is why I think about programming as an inexact science bording on the mystical.  Sometimes you just have to poke at things and experiment until something either works, or it sets your computer on fire.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## **LAUNCH IMAGES**

First, before anything else, you need to make sure you have the correct launch images included in your project.

Here is a table from [Adobe's website](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac1e63e3d129907d2886-8000.html#WS901d38e593cd1bac58d08f9112e26606ea8-8000):

- **Default~iphone.png**  |  iPhone 4 (non-retina) 640 x 960   *Potrait*
- **Default@2x~iphone.png** | iPhone 4, 4s  640 x 960  *Potrait*
- **Default-568h@2x~iphone.png** | iPhone 5, 5c, 5s 640 x 1136 *Potrait*
- **Default-375w-667h@2x~iphone.png** | iPhone 6/7/8 750 x 1334 *Potrait*
- **Default-414w-736h@3x~iphone.png** | iPhone 6+/7+/8+ 1242 x 2208 *Potrait*
- **Default-Landscape-414w-736h@3x~iphone.png** | iPhone 6+/7+/8+ 2208 x 1242 *Landscape*
- **Default-Landscape-812h@3x~iphone.png** | iPhone X 2436 x 1125 *Landscape*
- **Default-812h@3x~iphone.png** | iPhone X 1125 x 2436 *Portrait*

Once you have those images made (and named exactly as shown), include them in your project (They have to be in the ***root*** of your application) by doing the following:

In FlashPro

- go to your publish settings
- go to the AIR for iOS Settings.
- Go to the "General" tab
- add all those images to the "included files" list (the root)
  [image]

---

## **SCALING YOUR CONTENT**

- **OPTION 1, FILL AND CROP**

If you don't mind cropping your content a little bit, you can just do this when your app starts:

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_BORDER
```

This will scale your swf so it fills the whole screen while keeping aspect ratio.  It's pretty easy to figure out how much padding you need to make this method work well for the small variations in aspect ratios for the various iPhones.

However, if you want to allow orientation changes (portrait to landscape), the cropping will likely be too severe.

- **OPTION 2 - RESPONSIVE DESIGN**

The best way to accommodate varying screen resolutions and aspect ratios though, is to make your application responsive. This involves the following code at the start of your application:

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.align     = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
```

Now your stage bounds (`stage.stageWidth` & `stage.stageHeight`) will be the full width and height of the device*. (some devices still have a software toolbar at the bottom or the top band)

You can then position things through code.

If you want an easy way convert what you have (you don't want to use code to resize and align absolutely everything), just put all your content in a container MovieClip with an instance name of `container`, you could then size and position it like this:

```
//scale the container as big as possible while still fitting entirely in the screen:

//figure out which dimension should match the stage (widht or height)
if(container.width - stage.stageWidth >= container.height - stage.stageHeight){
    container.width = stage.stageWidth;
    container.scaleY = container.scaleX;
}else {
    container.height = stage.stageHeight
    container.scaleX = container.scaleY;
}

//center it on the screen:
container.x = (stage.stageWidth - container.width) * 0.5;
container.y = (stage.stageHeight - container.height) * 0.5;
```

It's also a good idea to listen for resize events, in case the screen size changes (eg you maximize/restore on desktop, or go from portrait to landscape on mobile).

You do that by listening for the resize event on the stage:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, redrawScreen);

function redrawScreen(e:Event):void {
    //resize everything as the window size has changed.
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've just tried stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_BORDER but nothing changes? I've still got black bars?

Comment: Where do have the code?  It should be on the first frame of your root timeline if using timelines. Also, you need to be deploying to AIR 3.5 or later.

Comment: I have the code in a layer called "actions", it's in the first frame on the timeline. That frame only contains a small amount of code. No matter what scaling mode I put in there nothing changes when I publish it out onto my iPhone. I get no error messages but it seems to have no effect. I'm running AIR 17.0.

Comment: Are you importing the classes your're referencing?  `import flash.display.StageScaleMode;`  should give you an error though if that was the problem.  Wish I had an ios device handy to test with, it's been a few years since I've done any iOS work.  DOes it work on the desktop?

Comment: Yeah I am importing that. On desktop it seems to work, when I resize it then  it resizes the rest of it (with a bit of cropping). Nothing happens, just black bars when I put it on the iPhone.

Comment: Actually, looks like your missing the "~iphone" in your launch image name shown in your question.

Comment: You absolute genius! I had the launch image name wrong, that's sorted it. You're right there is some cropping so tomorrow I will try out the second method you suggested. You've been a massive help, I'll select yours as the right answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You the coder are in charge of providing different solutions for different screen sizes. You check the device size and then you present the content accordingly. All in all it is not that different from showing different content based on rotation. If you hope for a magical solution that would do all that for you in AIR you are out of luck cos there's none.

Messing with the stage scalemodes is not recommended (you should always use no scale on mobile) as you then give up completely the ability to compare the position of your displayobject according the the real physical device size (basically you won't know for sure if whatever you display is in the screen or completely out of it).

If you thought developing for mobile was easy (not just using AIR but using any technology) then sorry, it's not especially cos you have to handle all those sizes.

The basic principle on how to deal with it:

1. get the real device size.
2. calculate the real density/ratio.
3. Compare that size to the size of your app. (again scale mode to no scale)
4. Extract a general ratio (size of your app compared to size of device)
5. Use that ratio to either, scale and place your main container (a container that contain your entire app), hard: scale and place all your DisplayObject in your app.
6. Since the app ratio is maintained fill the blank space with whatever.
7. Your app is filling correctly the entire screen on any device.