# Adobe Air application has black bars on iPhone 6 plus

Tags: ios, iphone, actionscript-3, air

I am having problem with my ios air app, shown in picture bellow. I can not get rid of black bars. Despite I added all launching images:

Any advice would be great help!

Images:

[image: launching images] [1]

Iphone6 plus screen

[image: screen from iphone] [2]

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34163821/1457439

Comment: You don't have the iPhone6+ launch image in your screenshot `Default-414w-736h@3x~iphone.png`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add launch images and compile them with your app

Default@2x.png    -  640px X 960px

Default-568h@2x.png  - 640px X 1136

Default-Portrait@2x.png   - 1536px X 2048px

you can read this for more details
http://blogs.adobe.com/airodynamics/2015/03/09/launch-images-on-ios-with-adobe-air/

or this : Update

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27473877/3623547

Comment: If you look at the question, those files exist.  Plus the ones you reference are not applicable for the phone mentioned (iPhone6+)

Comment: I'm sorry I've missed that check the second link

Answer (score 0):

Also I found than in IDE(FDT) i am using I can do this in this way:

[image: package contemts]