# Black Bars on Top and Bottom Overlay Content on iPhone 6s

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air

I'm using Adobe AIR 17 to create  an iOS app and tested on my iPhone 6S, I've included the launch images in my app, the content has been scaled correctly to full screen, but I still got black bars on top and bottom that overlay the content. I'm sure I named the launch images correctly and tried to include the below in my AS file, but still no luck:

```
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Launch images I've included:
Default.png, Default@2x.png, Default-568h@2x.png, Default-375w-667h@2x.png, Default-414w-736h@3x.png, Default-414w-736h-Landscape@3x.png

Comment: See my answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/34163821/1457439  -  copy and paste the launch image names from that.   You are missing the `~iphone` at the end of your names

Comment: I've checked on that thread before, some say with ~iPhone but some say without it, I tried both but still not working.

Comment: I mean the app on my phone has been scaled to full screen correctly, but there is still a black bar on top and bottom that overlay on the content.

Comment: Thanks anyway, it turns out the launch images need to be on the root directory folder.

Comment: I mention in that answer that the files need to be in the root. Glad you figured it out